# Is discrete valuation field a fraction field of some Dedekind domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, dedekind-domain

Is discrete valuation field a fraction field of some Dedekind domain ?

Let $K$ be a discrete valuation field, does there exist some Dedekind domain $R$ such that $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$＝$K$ ？

If there are some counterexamples, it's also appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For *any* valuation $v$ on the field $K$, with values in a totally ordered group $(G,+)$, the set
$$R=\{x\in K\mid v(x)\ge 0 \}$$
is a local subring of $K$, with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m=\{x\in K\mid v(x) >0 \}$, and for any $x\in K\smallsetminus A$, $x^{-1}\in K$.

Comment: Are you proving valuation field $R$ is Dedekind domain ?Could you tell me what is the definition of Dedekind domain here ?

Comment: No. I was explaining why, if the valuation is discrete, the ring $R$ is a discrete valuation domain, so that it is a Dedekind domain since it is a P.I.D.